# Query with count and maximum function

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have this table as the result of the followinq query:

```
select id, count(*) C
from t1
group by id

ID.   C 
01.   11
02.   21
03.   18
04.   09
05.   21
...
```

How can i get all the IDs associated to the maximum count? ( in my case 02 and 05 )

I tried with:

```
select id, count(*) C
from t1
group by id
where c= max(c)
```

but it does not work

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 5.x I would refer to a sub-query to get the max_c value you want to filter by...

```
select id, count(*) c
from t1
group by id
having c = (SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM t1 GROUP BY id) t1_agg)
```

Or...

```
select id, count(*) c
from t1
group by id
having c = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM t1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1
)
```

In MySQL 8 I would use a window function...

```
WITH
  t1_agg AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    COUNT(*)   AS c,
    MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER ()   AS max_c
  FROM
    t1
  GROUP BY
    id
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1_agg
WHERE
  c = max_c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, and just select the `id` that matches the `max(id)`, like...

```
SELECT FirstName, Count(id) AS count
FROM Person
GROUP BY FirstName
HAVING count = (
    SELECT MAX(count1)
    FROM (
        SELECT FirstName, Count(id) AS count1
        FROM Person
        GROUP BY FirstName
    )
p2)
```

Subqueries are a powerful tool, as it is...

> ...a SELECT statement within another statement. (Source: [Dev.MySQL.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html).)

Comment: I would also note that it needs to be a doubly nested sub-query...  `(SELECT MAX(c) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM t1 GROUP BY id) t1_agg)` which may not be immediately obvious to the OP.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thought I missed something, thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

If you can deal with the ids as a comma-delimited list, you could just use:

```
select cnt, group_concat(id)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t1
      group by id
     ) i
order by cnt
limit 1;
```